# Como retornar um objeto dynamic para um ajax

Tags: c#, jquery-datatables, dynamic

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Eu estou tentando trabalhar com objeto dynamic.

Eu tenho uma requisição ajax que pega um DataTable que possui colunas dinamicas e
desse DataTable eu preenchi um objeto Dynamic e agora preciso enviar esse objeto de volta para a requisição ajax carregar na página.

Só que depois que eu preenchi esse objeto dynamic eu não sei como prosseguir, alguém sabe me ajudar?

esse seria meu ajax:

```
 $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "url.aspx",
                    timeout: 999999,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var columns = [];
                        //tableLayout.destroy();

                        var myData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                        //var myData = data;
                        columnNames = Object.keys(myData.d[0]);
                        for (var i in columnNames) {
                            columns.push({
                                data: columnNames[i],
                                title: columnNames[i]
                            });
                        }

                        $('#tbl').DataTable({
                            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                            "bPaginate": false,
                            "orderCellsTop": true,
                            "bAutoWidth": false,
                            "bProcessing": false,
                            "bServerSide": false,
                            "bSort": false,
                            "bFilter": true,
                            "bLengthChange": true,
                            "bstateSave": true,
                            "scrollX": true,
                            "scrollY": "39vh",
                            "paging": false,
                            "scrollCollapse": true,
                            "bDestroy": true,                               

                            serverSide: false,
                            data: myData.d,
                            columns: columns,
                        })

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message);

                    }
            });
```

carregando o meu Object dymanic no codebehind:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static List<object> CarregarConsulta()
    {

        List<object> lista = new List<object>();

        DataTable dt = gerarDataTable();

        dynamic dynamicObject = "";


                foreach (DataRow item2 in dt.Rows)
                {
                   dynamicObject = new Dynamic();

                    var propertyName = "";
                    var propertyValue = "";
                    var x = "";
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        x = col.ColumnName;
                        propertyName = col.ColumnName;
                        propertyValue = item[x].ToString();

                        dynamicObject.AddProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);

                    
                    }
                }

          return lista;

        }
    }
```

isso porque eu tenho uma tela que retorna um relatório onde traz as colunas com dados do mês... Então o usuário pode escolher o mês que contêm 31 dias como 28 dias ou escolher mais de um mês que daria mais de 31 dias (retorna 01/01/2022, 02/02/2022)

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score -2):

Tenta isso:

```
 public static dynamic CarregarConsulta()
```

ou

```
 public static object CarregarConsulta()
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar a biblioteca JsonConvert e já que você cria um objeto dentro de iterações retorne uma string com seu objeto dynamic assim:

```
var response = new Dynamic();
/// suas iterações 
...
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject<dynamic>(response);
```

Já no seu ajax success, ficaria assim:

```
success: (response) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).